# How to disallow search pages from robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I need to disallow http://example.com/startup?page=2 search pages from being indexed.

I want http://example.com/startup to be indexed but not http://example.com/startup?page=2 and page3 and so on.

Also, startup can be random, e.g., http://example.com/XXXXX?page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this works, as confirmed by Google Webmaster Tools "test robots.txt" function:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /startup?page=
```

> Disallow The value of this field
>   specifies a partial URL that is not to
>   be visited. This can be a full path,
>   or a partial path; any URL that starts
>   with this value will not be retrieved.

However, *if the first part of the URL will change*, you must use wildcards:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /startup?page=
Disallow: *page=
Disallow: *?page=
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put this on the pages you do not want indexed:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NONE">
```

This tells robots not to index the page.

On a search page, it may be more interesting to use:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX,FOLLOW">
```

This instructs robots to not index the current page, but still follow the links on this page, allowing them to get to the pages found in the search.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a text file and name it: **robots.txt**
2. Add user agents and disallow sections (see sample below)
3. Place the file in the root of your site

Sample:

```
###############################
#My robots.txt file
#
User-agent: *
#
#list directories robots are not allowed to index 
#
Disallow: /testing/
Disallow: /staging/
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /assets/
Disallow: /images/
#
#
#list specific files robots are not allowed to index
#
Disallow: /startup?page=2
Disallow: /startup?page=3
Disallow: /startup?page=3
# 
#
#End of robots.txt file
#
###############################
```

Here's a link to Google's actual [robots.txt file](http://www.google.com/robots.txt)

You can get some good information on the Google webmaster's help topic on [blocking or removing pages using a robots.txt file](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449)

Comment: thanks for the answer, i forgot to add another detail here startup can be random /XXXXX?page

Comment: Using this method you'd have to manually add all the ?page=(number), you can leave that part off according to the spec.