# How i can remove a particular section of my website from Google who need to inaccessible for public user

Tags: indexing

I want to remove the dashboards section of my website from Google index how i can remove them from google then they never show them in search result.

Comment: Do a search for `robots.txt`. There are lots of duplicates here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disallow search pages from robots.txt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517541/how-to-disallow-search-pages-from-robots-txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add those pages to your [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) file or use a meta noindex tag to prevent Google from re-indexing it. Then in [Google's webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) you can instruct Google to remove the current version from their index (look under "Site configuration" → "Crawler access" in the menu on the left, then the "Remove URL" tab). You can also test your robots.txt in the same area.

See [Google's help](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=59819&hl=en) for more details.